# C - Why does assigning an element to a first element of adynamically allocated array always return nothing

Tags: c, stm32, fatfs

I am developing an application where I need to read some files off an SD Card. Everything runs on an STM32 microcontroller with FatFS. I just open the root, and iterate over each element in that directory and check whether it's a file or a folder, I save the information how many files I have. Then I allocate given amout of memory for said files (no of files x buffer for the name). Next, I read the directory again, like in the first step. This time I copy the name of each file to the aforementioned place in memory. My problem is, everytime I copy anything to the 2D array, the firs element contains literally nothing, and file names start from the second index. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Returns 0 on error or no files
uint8_t files_get_card_file_count(void)
{
    auto uint8_t file_count = 0;
    auto FRESULT result;
    auto DIR directory;
    auto FILINFO info;

    //Read card contents
    if(f_opendir(&directory, "/")) return 0;

    //Check if there is a card mounted and functioning
    if(disk_status(0) == (STA_NOINIT || STA_NODISK)) return 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        result = f_readdir(&directory,&info);              // Read a directory item
        if (result != FR_OK || info.fname[0] == 0) break;  // Break on error or end of dir
        if (!(info.fattrib & AM_DIR)) ++file_count;
    }
    return file_count;
}
```

```
//Make sure we dont allocate more than MAX_FILE_COUNT blocks
char** files_mem_allocate(uint8_t file_count)
{
    auto uint8_t i;

    char **array;
    array = calloc(file_count, sizeof(char *));

    if(array == NULL) return 0;

    for(i=0; i < file_count; i++)
    {
        array[i] = calloc(MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
        if(array[i] == NULL) return 0;
    }

    return array;
}
```

```
uint8_t files_get_names(char** array, uint8_t file_no)
{
    auto uint8_t i;
    auto FRESULT result;
    auto DIR directory;
    auto FILINFO info;

    //Read card contents
    if(f_opendir(&directory, "/")) return 1;

    //Check if there is a card mounted and functioning
    if(disk_status(0) == (STA_NOINIT || STA_NODISK)) return 1;

    for(i=0;i<file_no;i++)
    {
        result = f_readdir(&directory,&info);              //Read a directory item
        if (result != FR_OK || info.fname[0] == 0) break;  // Break on error or end of dir
        if (!(info.fattrib & AM_DIR))
        {
            //It is a file.
            //Mind the string safety?
            //Check bounds!
            strcpy(array[i], info.fname);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then if I do:
`lcd_str_XY(0,1, file_names_array[0]);`
There is nothing in this place in memory
`lcd_str_XY(0,1, file_names_array[1]);`
Prints the first file's name

Comment: Are there any nested directories in the one you are scanning? The first posted function counts the number of files incrementing the counter *only* if the item is a file, while in the last function the counter is incremented regardless.

Comment: No, there are just a couple text files

Answer (score 1):

`files_get_names` doesn't take into account anymore that `f_opendir` also returns directory. In fact, from your description it is likely that it returns a directory as the first entry. Yet `files_get_names` still increases the index and goes on.

Fix it like so:

```
uint8_t files_get_names(char** array, uint8_t file_no)
{
    auto uint8_t i;
    auto FRESULT result;
    auto DIR directory;
    auto FILINFO info;

    //Read card contents
    if(f_opendir(&directory, "/")) return 1;

    //Check if there is a card mounted and functioning
    if(disk_status(0) == (STA_NOINIT || STA_NODISK)) return 1;

    i = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        result = f_readdir(&directory,&info);              //Read a directory item
        if (result != FR_OK || info.fname[0] == 0) break;  // Break on error or end of dir
        if (!(info.fattrib & AM_DIR))
        {
            //It is a file.
            //Mind the string safety?
            //Check bounds!
            strcpy(array[i], info.fname);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. So after the first call of f_readdir() it fills the FILINFO structure with info about the currently opened directory? Did I get that correctly?

Comment: Let's say you have 1 directory and 3 files and f_readdir() returns them in the order dir, file1, file2, file3. So 4 entries, 3 files. Your original code only looped from 0 to 2, thus processing only dir, file1 and file2. It put file1 in the second and file2 in the array element and didn't do put anything in the first array element because f_readdir() returned a directory.

Comment: So it iterates over EVERYTHING on the card? I didn't have any folders created, that's what surprised me.

Comment: Not everything on the entire card, just everything in the root directory. Your code had two phases: (1) count all files, (2) retrieve names of files. In the second phase, it's only interested in files. But f_opendir() doesn't know that. It still returns directories too. But your original code didn't take this into account properly.